# Python Password Brute-Forcer

Tags: python

I'm working on a password brute-forcer that takes in a password from the user and brute-forces solutions until it finds a match. I was wondering if there is any way to improve performance or readability?

```python
import itertools
import time

Alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXiuYZ1234567890-_.")

Password = input("What is your password?\n")

start = time.time()

counter = 1

CharLength = 1

for CharLength in range(25):

    passwords = (itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat = CharLength))

    print("\n")

    print("Currently working on passwords with ", CharLength, " characters.")
    print("We are currently at ", (counter / (time.time() - start)), "attempts per second.")
    print("It has been ", time.time() - start, " seconds.")
    print("We have tried ", counter, " possible passwords.")

    for i in passwords:

        counter += 1

        i = str(i)

        i = i.replace("[", "")
        i = i.replace("]", "")
        i = i.replace("'", "")
        i = i.replace(" ", "")
        i = i.replace(",", "")
        i = i.replace("(", "")
        i = i.replace(")", "")

        if i == Password:

            end = time.time()

            timetaken = end - start

            print("\nPassword found in ", timetaken, " seconds and ", counter, "attempts.")

            print("That is ", counter / timetaken, " attempts per second.")

            print("\nThe password is \"%s\"." % i)

            input("\nPress enter when you have finished.")

            exit()
```

Thanks.

Comment: What would this code be used for? It asks for the plain text password, not a hash, and just iterates over all possible strings of length 0 through 24 until it matches what it already knows.

Comment: @l0b0 I'll later implement some sort of web form functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Some recommendations just looking at the style of the code:

1. It would benefit from being run through `pycodestyle`, `flake8` and/or similar tools to be more idiomatic. This would make the code easier to read for anyone familiar with Python.
2. Timing code should *not* be part of your program. External tools like `time` can handle that.
3. Use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) rather than `input` to make the program scriptable. The script should not stop anywhere to ask for input.
4. The `Alphabet` and `25` in this code are good candidates for configuration or parameters.
5. You can [remove all of a list of characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3939381/96588) in a single command.